# rmarkdown beamer presentation: how to not print section slides?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, beamer

I am writing a beamer presentation in rmarkdown and converting it to pdf with knitr. I want to define sections at the header1 level, e.g. `# Introduction`, and then have a slide titled something else e.g. `## Introducing my brilliant research`. Having the header1 level define sections is nice as the names of the sections can be displayed in the slide header in certain beamer themes, and this is why I include it.

But I do not want rmarkdown to insert a slide that simply says the name of the section between sections, which at the moment it is doing. Is there a way to not print a slide with the section name between sections? I thought `slide_level` would control this behavior but it does not seem to (or perhaps I am using it wrong).

A minimal reproducible example of my problem can be obtained with this code:

````
---
title: "Test Pres"
author: "Professor Genius Researcher"
date: "24 February 2017"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    slide_level: 2
    theme: "Singapore"
    colortheme: "rose"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

# Markdown Intro

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.

# Using Bullets

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

# Including Chunks

## Slide with R Output

```{r cars, echo = TRUE}
summary(cars)
```

## Slide with Plot

```{r pressure}
plot(pressure)
```
````

At the moment, this code produces slides that say Markdown Intro, Using Bullets, and Including Chunks. I would like those slides labeling the sections omitted. Is this possible?

Comment: Used `slide_level: 1`? Is this solving your problem?

Comment: no that makes the section title the title of the slide and puts all the subsequent slides into text boxes underneath it

Comment: Is removing the space after the header1 not what you had in mind either?

Comment: See [LaTeX Beamer prevent showing the TOC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795478/latex-beamer-prevent-showing-the-toc-at-one-occation), I tried replacing `# Including Chunks` with `\section*{Including Chunks}` but latex-engine pdflatex returns an error `! Missing \endgroup inserted.`

Comment: See also the [Rmarkdown help on advanced PDF customization](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#advanced-customization).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a new Latex template where you remove this part from the preamble:

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  ....
}
```

Place this latex template in the same folder as your .Rmd file and refer to it in the Rmd Yaml front matter using `template: mytemplate.tex` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604138/r-studio-change-pandoc-tex-template).

Comment: Brilliant. Many thanks indeed. One small change: the template file suggested via your link doesn't seem to cover beamer. I couldn't find the default beamer template on my system, so I got it [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.beamer) and did the edit as you suggested.

Comment: The template link above is broken, as the `default_beamer` template seems to be merged to [`default_latex`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex). At least, `default_latex` works for me.

Comment: Modifying YAML header with `header-includes: - \AtBeginSection{}` is also a viable option. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180441/dropping-frames-of-sections-and-subsections-titles-for-knitr-beamer-slides